# Unable to install Time:Piece module with cpan

Tags: windows, perl, windows-7

I need to install the `Time::Piece` module in Perl. It's not there for some reason. When I use

```
cpan install Time::Piece
```

after some successful steps I get the error below

```
.....
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Unable to find a perl 5 (by these names: "My windows path variable contents here...i think"
Writing Makefile for Time::Piece
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  RJBS/Time-Piece-1.29.tar.gz
  nmake -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 RJBS/Time-Piece-1.29.tar.gz                  : make NO

cpan[2]>
```

Why is this happening ? Please help me to fix it.

---

I'll wait for an answer while I try to fix it myself. First problem -

```
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I used [this solution](http://www.eureka.im/68.html)

> Windows 7  Control Panel, Programs and Features, Select Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008 Standard or Professional Edition application then
>   choose Uninstall/Change/Modify. This will bring you into Maintenance
>   Mode. Select C++ then check X64 Compilers and Tools.

I had Visual Studio Express and Visual Studio Professional 2013 (I don't remember how or why it's there on my system.) I followed the above instructions. The options were different: one had C++ mentioned in it - Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Microsoft Foundation Class Libraries. So, I chose that one. Its a 600MB download and install.

I went to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin` and found `nmake` there. If you don't find it there, then you might find in Microsoft Visual Studio 10, 11 etc. Look for `nmake` there. Add the path for `nmake` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Now, I get a new error

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:/Program'
Stop.
  RJBS/Time-Piece-1.29.tar.gz
  nmake -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 RJBS/Time-Piece-1.29.tar.gz                  : make NO

cpan[2]>
```

I'll try to fix this one too. By the way, `@ikegami` told me that installing to a path with no spaces (`C:\progs\...`) will solve my problem. I *cannot* install to another directory:

> This version of Perl comes bundled with other software which must
>   install to the folder `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` which has a space in it. The
>   software needs to be in that path for some other things to work
>   correctly. Is there a simple way to edit the code which is trying to install the modules? I could make it parse the path by changing some
>   code. I am new to Perl though. Not sure if I'll be able to change
>   without causing harm .

**EDIT -**

I have both Active state perl 5.1.2 and perl 5.8 which are used by tool x and tool y (electric commander). Tool y has its own perl libraries which must be used in my code. So I am stuck with perl 5.8.

I just came to know this is due to issues with tool y. There is a workaround for this, but I am not able to understand it. Can you please help me to understand the workaround for windows ?

https://electriccloud.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202828073-KBEC-00180-Installing-Perl-modules-into-the-Commander-Perl-distribution

Comment: How did you install perl itself?

Comment: If `Time::Piece` is missing then you have no idea what else may be wrong with the installation. You should reinstall everything rather than trying to patch what you have.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Perl are you running? what do you get if you run "perl -v" at a command prompt?

If the version number you get is 5.10 or higher, then Time::Piece should already be included with that version of Perl. If it's not, then your installation is broken in interesting ways and you should probably reinstall it from scratch.

If the version number you get is lower than 5.10 then you have a painfully old version of Perl installed and your best approach will be to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: You might find if it's ActiveState Perl, you can install via 'ppm' instead of CPAN. But if `Time::Piece` isn't there, then that probably means you've a really old perl, and rather than installing it by hand, updating Perl might be the answer.

Comment: I have both Active state perl 5.1 and perl 5.8 which are used by tool x and tool y (electric commander). Tool y has its own perl libraries which must be used in my code. So I am stuck with perl 5.8. I just came to know this is due to issues with tool y. There is a workaround for this, but I am not able to understand it. Can you please help ? https://electriccloud.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202828073-KBEC-00180-Installing-Perl-modules-into-the-Commander-Perl-distribution

Comment: Do you mean ActivePerl 5.001 or ActivePerl 5.10? There wasn't anything called Perl 5.1.

Comment: @DaveCross - I mean active perl 5.1.2. Btw, the electric commander instructions (to install modules) in my question are not very clear to me. Can you please help me to understand them and implement them ?

Comment: There is no such thing as Perl 5.1.2. What do you get if you type "perl -v" at a command line?